# Definition of Open Manifolds in Jeffrey Lee's differential geometry book

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

Definiton.

Manifold is an open manifold if it satisfies following to properties.

1. It has empty boundary
2. No component is compact.

   For example, the interior int(M) of a connected manifold M with nonempty boundary is never compact and is an open manifold in the above sense *if every component of M contains part of the boundary.*

Questions

1. M is assumed to be connected thus M has only one component i.e. itself. Thus every component of M contains part of the boundary.

I don't understand why the author stated *"if every component of M contains part of the boundary."*

2. int(M) is certainly not compact and without boundary.
   How can I prove that every component of int(M) is not compact?
   Is int(M) connected?

Comment: If $M$ is a compact manifold without boundary then $\operatorname{int} M = M$ and $M$ is not open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the word "connected" in the "For example, ..." was not supposed to be there; the rest of the paragraph suggests that to me. Once you believe that, the rest makes good sense.

Consider $M$ is the disjoint union of two line segments in the plane; the interior of $M$ is then the disjoin union of two open line segments in the plane, and the claim (that the interior of such a thing is an open manifold) is illustrated.

To see why the author included the condition that each component contain some of the boundary, consider the case where $M$ is the union of a circle and a (closed) line-segment in the plane. The interior of $M$ (the circle union the open line segment) is not an open manifold, because the circle component is compact. And that's because the circle didn't contain any of the boundary of $M$.

That's not to say that containing part of the boundary is a *necessary* condition -- it's merely a sufficient one. It's non-necessity is shown by the following:

Suppose we take as $M$ the union of that same closed interval and the whole $x$-axis. The interior of the union *is* in fact an open manifold, even though the $x$-axis part doesn't contain any boundary. And that's OK, because the author's claim is that *if* each component meets the boundary, *then* the interior is open, but not "only if". (I found the statement misleading as I read it, which is why I've included this apparently irrelevant example.)

Comment: The interior of the disjoint union of a circle and a line is not an open manifold, because it has a compact component.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your third paragraph. For some reason, I thought you said "suppose we take as $M$ the union of that same _circle_ and the whole $x$-axis." Forget my comment.

Comment: Oh, good. I've edited to try to make my explanation a little clearer, perhaps with some success. :)